# Laravel: Working a large number of tasks into a queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a web application using Laravel 5 that creates links to the web application that when visited show a form for a student's progress report. These links are sent by the web application to an email of a contact at the institution the student attends in order for the recipient to complete the progress report accessed by the link in the email.

The problem I face is when creating and sending links. I have some code which works fine with a couple of hundred students, however in real world use the application would be potentially creating and sending 3000+ or so links at one time. The code I've written simply can't handle such a large number in a timely manner and the application crashes. Strangely enough though I don't receive any timeout error via laravel (I'll need to double check the php logs).

Although I'm more than welcome to other suggestions, I believe the answer to the problem is utilising queues. I have already used queues when sending email (see code), but I would like to work some other parts of the code into queues, but I'm a bit unsure how to do this!

**Brief database schema**

`Student` hasMany `Link`

`Student` hasMany `InstitutionContact` (limited to two by my application)

`Link` hasMany `InstitutionContact` (limited to two by my application)

`Email` manyToMany `Link`

**What I am trying to accomplish**

- Get all the `Student`'s that require a new `Link`
- Create a `Link` for each `Student`
- Assign the `Student`'s current `InstitutionContact`s to the `Link`'s `InstitutionContact` (A `Student`'s institution contact can change, so I link the `InstitutionContact` to the link if needed to resend.
- Loop through all the newly created `Links` in order to group them together by shared `InstitutionContact`s - this is so an email is not sent per link (thus possibly sending many emails with one link to the same address), rather links should be grouped together by the same email/contact and sent together where applicable
- Loop through all the `Link`s grouped by email/contact and:

  1. Send an email including the `Link`'s info (url, student name etc) to the designated `InstitutionContact`'s email address
  2. Write a copy of the `Email` to the database
  3. Join the `Email` created in the former step to the `Link`(s) that were sent in it (so the application can be used to search what link was sent in which email)

So the main challenge I'm facing is performing the aforementioned task with a large dataset. I have already considered creating and sending a `Link` one by one via a queue, however this wouldn't allow me to group all the `Link`s together by contact/email. As the task wouldn't be performed regularly I would be open to consider performing the task as it is with an increase in memory and time for the process, however I didn't have much success when attempting this using `set_time_limit(0);` and `ini_set('memory_limit','1056M');` before sending any links.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you if you read this far!

**Code**

**app\Http\Controllers\LinkController.php**

```
public function storeAndSendMass(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'student_id' => 'required|array',
        'subject'    => 'required|max:255',
        'body'       => 'required|max:5000',
    ]);

    $studentIds = $request->get('student_id');
    $subject    = $request->get('subject');
    $body       = $request->get('body');

    $students = $this->student
        ->with('institutionContacts')
        ->whereIn('id', $studentIds)
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->get();

    // create link, see Link.php below for method
    $newLinks = $this->link->createActiveLink($students);

    // send link to student's contact(s), see LinkEmailer.php below for method
    $this->linkEmailer->send($newLinks, ['subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body], 'mass');

    // return
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Creating and sending links'
    ]);
}
```

**app\Models\Link.php**

```
public function createActiveLink($students)
{
    $links = [];

    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $newLink = $this->create([
            'token'          => $student->id, // automatically hashed
            'status'         => 'active',
            'sacb_refno'     => $student->sacb_refno,
            'course_title'   => $student->course_title,
            'university_id'  => $student->university_id,
            'student_id'     => $student->id,
            'institution_id' => $student->institution_id,
            'course_id'      => $student->course_id,
        ]);

        $studentContacts = $student->institutionContacts;

        if ($studentContacts) {

            foreach ($studentContacts as $studentContact) {

                $newLink->contacts()->create([
                    'type'                   => $studentContact->pivot->type,
                    'institution_contact_id' => $studentContact->pivot->institution_contact_id
                ]);

                $newLink->save();
            }

        }

        $links[] = $newLink->load('student');
    }

    return $links;
}
```

**app\Emails\LinkEmailer.php**

```
namespace App\Emails;

use App\Emails\EmailComposer;

class LinkEmailer
{
    protected $emailComposer;

    public function __construct(EmailComposer $emailComposer)
    {
        $this->emailComposer = $emailComposer;
    }

    public function send($links, $emailDetails, $emailType)
    {        
        $contactsAndLinks = $this->arrangeContactsToLinks($links);

        foreach ($contactsAndLinks as $linksAndContact) {

            $emailData = array_merge($linksAndContact, $emailDetails);

            // send/queue email
            \Mail::queue('emails/queued/reports', $emailData, function ($message) use ($emailData) {
                $message
                    ->to($emailData['email'], $emailData['formal_name'])
                    ->subject($emailData['subject']);
            });

            // compose email message, returns text of the email
            $emailMessage = $this->emailComposer->composeMessage($emailData);

            // // create Email
            $email = \App\Models\Email::create([
                'to'      => $emailData['email'],
                'from'    => 'report@domain.org',
                'subject' => $emailData['subject'],
                'body'    => $emailMessage,
                'type'    => $emailType,
                'user'    => $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']
            ]);

            foreach ($linksAndContact['links'] as $link) {
                $link->emails()->attach($email->id);
            }
        }
    }

    // group links by contact
    public function arrangeContactsToLinks($links)
    {
        $contactsForLinks = [];
        $assigned         = false;
        $match            = false;

        foreach ($links as $link) { // 1, n

            if ($link->contacts) {

                foreach ($link->contacts as $contact) { // 1, 2

                    if ($contactsForLinks) {

                        $assigned = false;

                        foreach ($contactsForLinks as $key => $contactLink) { // n
                            // assign links to existing email in array
                            if ($contactLink['email'] === $contact->institutionContact->email) {
                                $match = false;

                                // check link hasn't already been included
                                foreach ($contactsForLinks[$key]['links'] as $assignedLink) {
                                    if ($assignedLink === $link) {
                                        $match = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                // if there was no match add to list of links
                                if (!$match) {
                                    $contactsForLinks[$key]['links'][] = $link->load('student');
                                    $assigned = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (!$assigned) {
                            $contactsForLinks[] = [
                                'email'                 => $contact->institutionContact->email,
                                'formal_name'           => $contact->institutionContact->formal_name,
                                'requires_id'           => $contact->institutionContact->institution->requires_id,
                                'requires_course_title' => $contact->institutionContact->institution->requires_course_title,
                                'links'                 => [$link->load('student')],
                            ];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $contactsForLinks[] = [
                            'email'                 => $contact->institutionContact->email,
                            'formal_name'           => $contact->institutionContact->formal_name,
                            'requires_id'           => $contact->institutionContact->institution->requires_id,
                            'requires_course_title' => $contact->institutionContact->institution->requires_course_title,
                            'links'                 => [$link->load('student')],
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $contactsForLinks;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

I've got this working now with `set_time_limit(0);` and `ini_set('memory_limit','1056M');` it took 8 mins to do 3000 students.

**Edit 2**

I'm running Laravel Framework version 5.1.6 (LTS), MySQL for DB.

**Edit 3**

Appreciate all the answers so far, thank you all. I am thinking that I may work the `link` creation process into a queue which will have a related entity in the database called something like `Batch` and when that `Batch` of links has finished being created then group all the `Link`s from that `Batch` and send them.

I could use the approach that @denis-mysenko suggested by having a `sent_at` field in the `Link`s table and have a scheduled process to check for `Link`s that haven't been sent and then send them. However, using the aforementioned approach I can send the `Batch` of `Link`s when they've all finished being created, whereas with the `sent_at` approach with a scheduled process looking for `Link`s that haven't been sent it could potentially send some links when all the links haven't been created yet.

Comment: I can recommend some sort of `data index` for handling huge data collections. F.a. `Elasticsearch` or `Apache Lucene`. The disadvantage is, you have to put the data you need into the index and maintain it but then you can access millions of entries within split seconds.

Comment: It might be a bit beyond what I'm looking for but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you do not have an error log it might be caused by a memory exhaustion

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.0, 5.1, or 5.2?

Comment: @CaptainHypertext `5.1.6`

Answer (score 2):

If you've tested your code with a small amount of data and it succeeds without crashing, it's clear that the problem is (as you said) the quite high number of records you're dealing with. Why don't you process your collection with the **chunk** method?

Accordingly to the Laravel docs:

> If you need to process thousands of Eloquent records, use the chunk command. The chunk method will retrieve a "chunk" of Eloquent models, feeding them to a given Closure for processing. Using the chunk method will conserve memory when working with large result sets

Anyway, I think the use of a queue it's required in this kind of scenarios. I believe that working on a large set of data on a HTTP request should be absolutely avoided due to the high risk of request timeout. The queued process doesn't have the limit of execution time.

Why don't you use the queue AND the chunk method on your collection together? This will make you able to:

- avoid timeout errors
- use a reasonable amount of memory during the execution of the process (this depends on the number of data passed to the chunk closure)
- give you priority control over this queued process and (eventually) other queued processes

The Laravel docs covers all you need: [Eloquent - Retrieving multiple models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models) (see the "Chunking results" chapter for going deeper on how to save memory when dealing with a large data set) and [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues) for creating jobs and detach some parts of your software that should not run under your webserver, avoiding the risk of timeouts

Comment: Thanks for your reply @andrew-reborn I will see if chunking makes a difference. My key issue however is that I can't just push all the links to be sent in a queue, I firstly have to re-organise the links that I create to be grouped by a common email address (where the recpipient is the same) and I can only do that with all the links ready at one time. I guess identifying where the process is taking up a lot of memory would be a start then see how I can optimise that.

Comment: Why don't you give this (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) a try? Should help you to reach your goal identifying the most intensive parts of your algorithm.

Comment: I see you're doing this in the first foreach statement of arrangeContactsToLinks method: $link->contacts. This is (maybe) one of the reasons you're getting poor performances on your algorithm. Consider the difference between eager and lazy loading can lead to very poor performance... If you're sure you need a related data, always get It taking advantage of the eager loading (the with statement in other words). When you lazy load a related data and you try to retrieve it, you're implicitly making a select query for each parent model

Comment: Thanks I'm using the debugbar. I've tried using eager loading in some places but sometimes strangely it doesn't pass through to the next method, hope that makes sense. I will reinvestigate this issue and edit the question accordingly, most likely I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the cited documentation and an example of code? Thanks.

Comment: @A.L If you scroll down a bit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

Comment: @haakym I'm not interested in the answer specifically, I was suggesting to improve the answer by showing a link and some code, I may be useful to other visitors to have a code example instead of *Why don't you use …*.

Comment: @A.L got it, on my way to add some references to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to change the architecture. I think it's unnecessarily overcomplicated.

Controller could like like:

```
public function storeAndSendMass(Request $request, LinkEmailer $linkEmailer)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'student_id' => 'required|array',
        'subject'    => 'required|max:255',
        'body'       => 'required|max:5000',
    ]);

    $students = $this->student
        ->with('institutionContacts')
        ->whereIn('id', $request->input('student_id'))
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->get();

    // Don't use Link.php method at all
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $student->links()->create([
            'token'          => $student->id, // automatically hashed
            'status'         => 'active',
            'sent_at'        => null,
            'email_body'     => $request->input('body'),
            'email_subject'  => $request->input('subject')
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Creating and sending links'
    ]);
}
```

Why keep so many fields in Link model that already exist in Student model and are accessible via student() relationship? You could just keep the status and the token (I assume it's part of the link?), as well as 'sent_at' timestamp. If links are usually sent only once, it's reasonable to keep the email body and subject there as well.

If student updates his institution contacts, fresh data will be used at the time of email composition because you are not linking links to institution contacts explicitly.

Then, I would create a command (let's say newLinkNotifier) that would run, for instance, every 10 minutes and that would look for links that haven't been sent yet (`$links->whereNull('sent_at')`), group them by email (`$link->student->institutionContacts`) and email content (`$link->email_body, $link->email_subject`) and create queued email jobs. Then a queue worker would send those emails (or you could set queue to 'async' to send them right away from the command).

Since this command will run async, it doesn't really matter if it takes 5 minutes to finish. But in real life, it would take less than a minute for thousands and thousands of objects.

How to do the grouping? I would probably just rely on MySQL (if you are using it), it will do the job faster than PHP. Since all 3 fields are accessible from SQL tables (two directly, another from JOIN) - it's actually a pretty simple task.

In the end your emailers send() method will become as trivial as:

```
public function send()
{        
    $links = Link::whereNull('sent_at')->get();

    // In this example, we will group in PHP, not in MySQL
    $grouped = $links->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return implode('.', [$item->email, $item->email_body, $item->email_subject]);
    });

    $grouped->toArray();

    foreach ($grouped as $group) {
        // We know all items in inside $group array got the same
        // email_body, email, email_subject values anyway!
        Mail::queue('emails/queued/reports', $group[0]->email_body, function ($message) use ($group) {
            $message
                ->to($group[0]->email)
                ->subject($group[0]->email_subject);
        });    
    }
}
```

This is not perfect yet, and I haven't tested this code - I wrote it right here, but it shows the proposed concept.

If you don't plan to get millions of entries - this is probably good enough. Otherwise, you could move link creation into a separate async job as well.

Comment: "Why keep so many fields in Link model that already exist in Student model and are accessible via student() relationship?" Good question, a student's course, institution, contacts etc. can change, therefore when creating the link I keep the student's details that can change and are relevant to the link within the link. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "If links are usually sent only once, it's reasonable to keep the email body and subject there as well." A link can be sent to multilpe contacts and because links are grouped together by contacts within an email before being sent the email body could potentially be different for each recipient.

Comment: I like your idea about creating a `sent_at` field, so where null it hasn't been sent and have a process looking out for links not sent and process them. I also think you're definitely on to something regarding the grouping of links by sql > php. I'll see if I can work this into something. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: Oh and yes I am using `MySQL`

Comment: If you want to attach a snapshot of the current student to a link - I would rather use just one VARCHAR field and store serialized (json_encode($student)) model there. At the moment database/models look misleading a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The current approach makes sense for me and I fully appreciate you don't have the full requirements/functionality of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running version 5.0, how about passing off that initial processing to the queue as well?

**app\Http\Controllers\LinkController.php**

```
 // Accept request, validate $students

 // Send this work strait to the cue
 Bus::dispatch(
    new CreateActiveLinks($students));
 );

// return
return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Creating and sending links. This will take a while.'
]);
```

**app\Console\Commands\CreateActiveLinks.php** (queued job)

```
class CreateActiveLinks extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue {

    protected $studentIds;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($studentIds)
    {
        $this->studentIds = $studentIds;
    }

    /**
     * This part is executed in the queue after the
     * user got their response
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $students = Student::with('institutionContacts')
            ->whereIn('id', $studentIds)
            ->where('is_active', 1)
            ->get();

        foreach ($students as $student) {
            // Process and create records...

            $newLinks[] = $newLink->load('student');
        }

        // Emailer job would run like normal
        LinkEmailer::send($newLinks, ['subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body], 'mass');

        // Notify user or something...
    }
}
```

[Queuing Commands in Laravel 5.0](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#queued-commands)

In 5.1 forward, these are called [Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes) and work a little differently.

This code is untested, and I don't have a firm grasp on your application structure, so please don't take it as gospel.  It's just based on work I've done in my own application when faced with similar circumstances.  Maybe this will at least give you some ideas.  If you really have a lot of records, then adding the `chunk()` method in the `CreateActiveLinks` class query might be helpful.

Comment: Extracting the links creation process to a job was actually what I had in mind so thanks for the suggestion and the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that creating an Event/Listener and them implementing queue is a lot more easier. All you have to is to create an Event and Listener for your email process(LinkEmailer) and then implement ShouldQueue interface as mentioned in the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#queued-event-listeners

Comment: You mean easier than creating a queued job?